# Using Jquery to loop using z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay, so this might be a dumb question but I have been trying to get my divs to overlap each other using the z-index. However I cannot seem to manage how I actually loop it by changing the z-index itself. The code will be found below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#map1").click(function(){
    $("#map1").slideUp("slow");
  });
  $("#map2").click(function(){
    $("#map2").slideUp("slow");
  });
  $("#map3").click(function(){
    $("#map3").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#map1, #map2, #map3, #map4
{
  width: 99%;
  height: 98%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#map1 { z-index: 999; }
#map2 { z-index: 998; }
#map3 { z-index: 997; }
#map4 { z-index: 996; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maps">
  <div id="map1">Map 1</div>
  <div id="map2">Map 2</div>
  <div id="map3">Map 3</div>
  <div id="map4">
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's no slide for map4 but that's because I want to put a reset button on that div that'll make the page jump back to page 1. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to make the divs slideUp() after each click, or one after another consecutively?

Comment: After every click, however I have currently been using a .slideDown command which triggers every time I press the reset button. It works for the time being but it's a bit trashy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rely on the z-order. Just use the order in the DOM, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".map").click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp("slow");
  });
  $("#reset").click(function(){
    $(".map").slideDown("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#map1, #map2, #map3, #map4
{
  width: 99%;
  height: 98%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#map1
{
  background: red;
}
#map2
{
  background: green;
}
#map3
{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maps">
  <div id="map4">
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <div id="map3" class="map">Map 3</div>
  <div id="map2" class="map">Map 2</div>
  <div id="map1" class="map">Map 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Demo #1](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lutdcfs/)

```js
var m1 = $("#map1").css("z-index"),
 m2 = $("#map2").css("z-index"),
 m3 = $("#map3").css("z-index"),
 m4 = $("#map4").css("z-index");


if (m1 > m2 || m1 > m3 || m1 > m4) {
 $("#map1").css("display", "block");
 $("#map2 , #map3 , #map4").css("display", "none");
} else if (m2 > m1 || m2 > m3 || m2 > m4) {
 $("#map2").css("display", "block");
 $("#map1 , #map3 , #map4").css("display", "none");
} else if (m3 > m1 || m3 > m2 || m3 > m4) {
 $("#map3").css("display", "block");
 $("#map1 , #map2 , #map4").css("display", "none");
} else if (m4 > m1 || m4 > m2 || m4 > m3) {
 $("#map4").css("display", "block");
 $("#map1 , #map2 , #map3").css("display", "none");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#map1").click(function(){
    $("#map1").slideUp("slow", m1Callback );
    function m1Callback() { $("#map2").slideDown("slow"); }
  });

  $("#map2").click(function(){
    $("#map2").slideUp("slow", m2Callback );
    function m2Callback() { $("#map3").slideDown("slow"); }
  });

  $("#map3").click(function(){
    $("#map3").slideUp("slow", m3Callback );
    function m3Callback() { $("#map4").slideDown("slow"); }
  });

  $("#map4").click(function(){
    $("#map4").slideUp("slow", m4Callback );
    function m4Callback() { $("#map1").slideDown("slow"); }
  });

});
```

```css
#map1, #map2, #map3, #map4
{
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc
}

#map1 { z-index: 999; }
#map2 { z-index: 998; }
#map3 { z-index: 997; }
#map4 { z-index: 996; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maps">
  <div id="map1">Map 1</div>
  <div id="map2">Map 2</div>
  <div id="map3">Map 3</div>
  <div id="map4">
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> [Demo #2](https://jsfiddle.net/ehx21sq7/)

```js
var m1 = $("#map1").css("z-index"),
 m2 = $("#map2").css("z-index"),
 m3 = $("#map3").css("z-index"),
 m4 = $("#map4").css("z-index");

if (m1 > m2 || m1 > m3 || m1 > m4) {
 $("#map1").css("display", "block");
 $("#map2 , #map3 , #map4").css("display", "none");
} else if (m2 > m1 || m2 > m3 || m2 > m4) {
 $("#map2").css("display", "block");
 $("#map1 , #map3 , #map4").css("display", "none");
} else if (m3 > m1 || m3 > m2 || m3 > m4) {
 $("#map3").css("display", "block");
 $("#map1 , #map2 , #map4").css("display", "none");
} else if (m4 > m1 || m4 > m2 || m4 > m3) {
 $("#map4").css("display", "block");
 $("#map1 , #map2 , #map3").css("display", "none");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#map1").click(function(){
    $("#map1").slideUp("slow");
    $("#map2").slideDown("slow");
  });
  $("#map2").click(function(){
    $("#map2").slideUp("slow");
    $("#map3").slideDown("slow");
  });
  $("#map3").click(function(){
    $("#map3").slideUp("slow");
    $("#map4").slideDown("slow");
  });
  $("#map4").click(function(){
    $("#map4").slideUp("slow");
    $("#map1").slideDown("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#map1, #map2, #map3, #map4
{
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc
}

#map1 { z-index: 999; }
#map2 { z-index: 998; }
#map3 { z-index: 997; }
#map4 { z-index: 996; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maps">
  <div id="map1">Map 1</div>
  <div id="map2">Map 2</div>
  <div id="map3">Map 3</div>
  <div id="map4">
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```